# jQuery of required field validation not working

Tags: jquery

I have created this very simple code just for my practice. I am trying to test the jQuery for the required fields. But it is not working. Can someone tell me why? Also, it would be really helpful if you can also tell how can I improve it. I was thinking to make it even better by displaying error message below the field instead of the alert box and also to change the text field colour to red if an error occurred.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    if ($('#fn').val() == "" || $('#ln').val() == "") {
      alert('Please complete the required field(s)');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color : black">
  <br /><br /><br />
  <div style="text-align:center; color:white;">
    <form>
      <strong> 
      First Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input id = "fn" type = "text" /> <br /><br />
      Middle Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input id = "ln" type = "text" /> <br /><br />
      Last Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" /> <br /><br />
      Gender &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <select> 
          <option value = "Male">Male</option>
          <option value = "Female">Female</option>
           </select> <br /><br />
      Married &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <select> 
          <option value = "No">No</option>
          <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
                 </select> <br /><br />
      Spouse Name &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" /> <br /><br />
      DOB &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "date" /> <br /><br />
      Email &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" /> <br /><br />
      Age &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" /> <br /><br />
      Mobile &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" /> <br /><br /><br />
      <button class="btn"> SUBMIT </button>
      </strong>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: you can use jquery validation or form  validation plugin instead

Comment: Clicking a `<button>` (without a `type`) inside of a `<form>` will submit the form. If there's an error, you need to prevent the submit from going through. [Read more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Comment: I created a snippet for you by clicking the `<>`

Comment: 1. Use the submit event
2. Use preventDefault to not submit: `$(function() {
  $('form').on("submit",function(e) {
    if ($('#fn').val() == "" || $('#ln').val() == "") {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      alert('Please complete the required field(s)');
    }
  });
});`

Comment: To not have to do anything, add the `required` attribute to each field tag

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    debugger;
    var isValidForm = validateFields();
    if (isValidForm) {

      //code to submit form
    }
  });
});

function validateFields() {

  var isValid = true;
  $('.validate').each(function(index, object) {
    if (!$(object).val()) {
      isValid = false;
      $(object).siblings('.error-msg').show();
    }
  });
  return isValid;
}
```

```css
* {
  color: black
}

.error-msg {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center; ">

  First Name
  <input id="fn" type="text" class="validate" />
  <p class="error-msg">Required</p>
  <br /><br /> Gender
  <select class="validate">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
  </select>
  <p class="error-msg">Required</p><br /><br />

  <button class="btn"> SUBMIT </button>

</div>
```